# On joining two tables how to get desired output using SQL query?

Tags: sql

There are two sample tables

- `tblEmployee`
- `tblProjectDetails`

On joining two tables how to get the desired output as shown in the final table? Need an SQL query? Or any other better to accomplish in C# and .net?

**tblEmployee**

```
EMP_ID EMP_Name EMP_Email
1    Hanu   hanu@gmail.com
2    Chetan chetan@gmail.com
3    Vishal vishal@yahoo.com
```

**tblProjectDetails**

```
EMP_ID    EMP_ProjectName   EMP_ProjectDetails
1     Project1            Asset Management
1     Project2            Inventory Mangament
2     Project3            PMT
2     Project4            Stores Managemnt
3     Project5            RFID
```

**tblResult**

```
EMP_ID    EMP_Name   EMP_Email         EMP_ProjectName          EMP_ProjectDetails
1         Hanu       hanu@gmail.com        Project1              Asset Management
                                           Project2              Inventory Mangament
2         Chetan     chetan@gmail.com      Project3              PMT
                                           Project4              Stores Managemnt
3         Vishal     vishal@yahoo.com      Project5              RFID
```

Comment: You need neither the c# or the .net tags. Do you want to generate the result table, or just present the results to  a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this query**

```
create view tblResult 
   select 
       tblEmployee.EMP_ID, tblEmployee.EMP_NAME, tblEmployee.EMP_MAIL, 
       tblProjectDetails.EMP_ProjectName, tblProjectDetails.EMP_ProjectDetails 
FROM
tblEmployee 
INNER JOIN 
    tblProjectDetails on tblEmployee.EMP_ID = tblProjectDetails.EMP_ID
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!